# Swift and Javascript different Bitwise calculation results

Tags: javascript, swift, hash, bitwise-operators

I am trying to port over a Javascript hashing function to Swift:

In Javascript:
`68207947269 ^ 51` = `-511529418`

where as the same calculation in Swift 5

`68207947269 ^ 51` = `68207947318`

How, why are they different?

Edit, added the JS hashing function

```
function hash(str) {
  var hash = 5381,
      i    = str.length;

  while(i) {
    hash = (hash * 33) ^ str.charCodeAt(--i);
  }

  /* JavaScript does bitwise operations (like XOR, above) on 32-bit signed
   * integers. Since we want the results to be always positive, convert the
   * signed int to an unsigned by doing an unsigned bitshift. */
  return hash >>> 0;
}
```

Edit 2, added current broken Swift:

```
extension String {
    subscript(i: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)])
    }
}

extension Character {
    func unicodeScalarCodePoint() -> UInt32 {
        let characterString = String(self)
        let scalars = characterString.unicodeScalars
        return scalars[scalars.startIndex].value
    }
}

func hashString(_ string: String) -> UInt32 {
    var hash: Int32 = 5381
    var i = string.count - 1
    while(i >= 0) {
        let char = Int32(Character(string[i]).unicodeScalarCodePoint())
        // Crash here with error: `Swift runtime failure: arithmetic overflow`
        let hashMultiply = Int32(truncating: NSNumber(value: hash * 33))
        hash = hashMultiply ^ char
        i -= 1
    }
    return UInt32(bitPattern: hash)
}

hashString("0x8f1083db77b5F556E46Ac46A29DE86e01031Bb14")
```

Comment: What types are you working with in Swift? Or did you just enter that as one expression?

Comment: I know Javascript works in Int32s for it calculations, I tried that but no luck - to be honest, Swift wise I dont mind what types I use

Comment: @idmean I added current broken Swift. It still breaks even with the `Int32(truncatingIfNeeded:` update

Comment: On which line does this error occur? If you split up your calculations over several lines that would certainly help in debugging.

Comment: And why are you doing `NSNumber(value: hash * 33)`?

Comment: It forces me too "Cannot convert value of type 'Int32' to expected argument type 'NSNumber'"

Comment: I added input string and split up the calculations in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp), bitwise operators in JavaScript use 32-bit operands. 68207947269 is too large to be represented in 32 bits, so it gets truncated first automatically, then the bitwise operation is carried out.

Swift integer literals are of type `Int` by default, and the size of `Int` is platform-dependent. It is most likely 64-bits for you, which is why the different result is produced.

To produce the same result as the JavaScript code, convert it to `Int32` by truncating first:

```
Int32(truncatingIfNeeded: 68207947269) ^ 51
```

Note that you get a `Int32` as a result. You might need to do more type conversions later on.

---

About your Swift translation, I see two main problems.

Firstly, `hash * 33` will overflow and cause a crash. The JavaScript version doesn't need to worry about this because the result will simply "wrap around" in JavaScript. Fortunately, there is an [operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID37) that also "wraps around" if the result overflows (rather than crashing) in Swift. So you can do:

```
hash &* 33
```

Secondly, you are handling strings differently from the JavaScript version. In JavaScript, [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) returns a UTF-16 code unit, but your Swift code gets the unicode scalar instead.

To get the same behaviour, you should do:

```
extension String.UTF16View {
    subscript(i: Int) -> Element {
        return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)]
    }
}

...

Int32(string.utf16[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that [in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR):

> The operands are converted to 32-bit integers and expressed by a series of bits (zeroes and ones). Numbers with more than 32 bits get their most significant bits discarded.

Integer literals in Swift are of type `Int` by default, which is your architecture's word width. If you tried this on any recent Apple device, it'll be 64-bit.

So to mimic JavaScript behavior, you would need to cast to an Int32:

```
Int32(truncatingIfNeeded: 68207947269) ^ Int32(51)
```

which gives the desired result `-511529418`.

Note that your JavaScript code discards bits of the integer 68207947269 as it cannot be represented as a 32-bit integer.